# Can I access DLC items through the console if I'm under level 10? Or is the DLC not active?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have currently re-visited my Skyrim game on the PC and started a fresh game. I have all the DLCs and the unofficial graphics patches and so on.

Now when running the game I know I need to be level 10 to activate them however are item codes still working if the DLC hasn't been "Activated" in game? 
Like I tried to use a player.additem command as I had not seen the Nordic Carved armour and wanted to see it... It says its an invalid item code.

Now I'm stuck between whether its the DLC that is broken or whether it will work when I reach level 10...
so the question is: If I have the DLCs installed would I still be able to get the DLC items with the command or would I need to be level ten for them to be available?

Comment: The DLC is `activated` when you start the game. What happens at level 10 in Dragonborn is that the main quest is triggered. You can start the DLC early by boarding the boat at Wildhelm docks and speaking to the captain, Gjalund Salt-Sage.

Comment: I may not have worded it correctly as I know the level does not "activate" the DLC installation or anything of that nature. I was more thinking along the lines of should I get to level ten and then if the DLC quest becomes available I will know my dlc is working correctly. I didn't know if the game blocked all of the items as well as the quests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the console commands to add items requires only that the item exist within the .ESM and .ESP files loading into the game - *your character level makes no difference at all*. That means if you open the game loader (where you change graphics settings) and open "Data Files" it's the files that are selected. You may use a mod manager, such as Nexus Mod Manager, which will also give you this view. **So first check that Dragonborn is selected**.

If it is then you need to make sure you have the correct item code - the code for Nordic Carved Armour is `xx01cd97` - there the `xx` corresponds to the index of the Dragonborn plugin. To find this, head back into the "Data Files" or the plugin list and find Dragonborn.esm. The data files won't have a number so you'll need to count from the top to find which number Dragonborn is - **remember to start at `0`, not `1`!**. If you use a mod manager that will most likely show you the index - the first file (`Skyrim.esm`) will be 0.

So if Dragonborn.esm is the fifth item in the list, the index will be `4`, which makes the item code `0401cd97`. If this still doesn't seem to work use this command:

`help "Nordic Carved Armour" 0` - this will search for it and provide the code. This is a fast way of finding any item instead of looking it up elsewhere.

If this doesn't find it then Dragonborn cannot be loaded. The first step would be to check for mod incompatibilities.

Comment: That last command has saved me so much work! If I could upvote this again I would I will try that as soon as I get back from work tonight. Thanks for a great answer. :)

Comment: @ThunderToes Glad it helped. It's just one vote per person but I appreciate the pretence. Just bear in mind the search can be a pain for things with a short, common name, such as "Leather" (lots of things have "Leather" in the name), so it may be worth looking up the code over at UESP.net

Comment: Yeah this worked fine I ordered my DLCs and used the help command. All sorted and most of all my game isnt broken! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to be level 10 to activate them" is a weird sentence. DLC content has some guards so that it doesn't start when you're underleveled, but that's not at all the same as activating DLC. Are they active in your load order? If they are any codes for DLC content will work as well.

As for why it didn't work involves a bit of guesswork, but the most likely answer, is that you input the code wrong. First two characters (which are given as 00 on most sites, sometimes as XX) are a reference to the games load order, to see in what file to find that item - 00 is the main game, 01 is the first mod/dlc after that and so on. I don't know what you tried, but try altering them up to see if one works - one of 01, 02 or 03 should.

Answer (score -1):

i have noticed this oddity recently for what ever reason game just fails to recognise the codes used... but in terms of if you have to be a level to use said codes no you dont you can be level 100 or level 1 doesn't matter its just somthing wierd with the game or probaby a mod.

as for the claim that you have to be level 10 to trigger either the dawnguard dlc content or dragonborn dlc content is also completly wrong you dont hve to be level 10 to trigger them. for dawnguard go to any town and you'll eventually get approached by an orc this usually happens when first entering any city or town (pendent on if you use an alternate start mod)

for dragonborn you can start it early by boarding a boat from windhelm but if you have not used this method the cultist will only start appearing in skyrim after you get the note delphine leaves in place of the horn ure sent to collect by the greybeards